# Android app not running on emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-ndk

```
[2010-06-15 12:01:37 - helloNDK]Android Launch!
[2010-06-15 12:01:37 - helloNDK]adb is running normally. 
[2010-06-15 12:01:37 - helloNDK]Performing com.android.helloNDK.helloNDK activity launch
[2010-06-15 12:01:37 - helloNDK]Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2010-06-15 12:01:37 - helloNDK]Uploading helloNDK.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-06-15 12:01:37 - helloNDK]Installing helloNDK.apk...
[2010-06-15 12:01:40 - helloNDK]Success!
[2010-06-15 12:01:40 - helloNDK]Starting activity com.android.helloNDK.helloNDK on device 
[2010-06-15 12:01:41 - helloNDK]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2010-06-15 12:01:42 - helloNDK]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
[2010-06-15 12:01:42 - helloNDK]ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { comp={com.android.helloNDK/com.android.helloNDK.helloNDK} }
```

When I run the application in eclipse it says there is a problem with the application and it needs to close. "Cant dispatch DDM" is the error message.

Comment: Can you post some code for us?

Comment: a restart of the system can help. It happened to me once

Answer (score 1):

The "Can't dispatch DDM chunk" message is probably not the real problem. They're an error in the application launch. Might be that you forgot to put the first activity in the AndroidManifest or to specify it as Launcher; or the @OnCreate method for the first activity has a error in it.